# Postfix Evaluation how to detect operator vs operand

Tags: c++

I have this Code in which I am using character array to store each expression but it doesnt work with `numbers >9` my current code is:

```
int main(){
    int i,n,c,k,l; 
    char buf[200];
    cin>>n;
    IntStack s(n);
    i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        cin>>buf[i];

        if(buf[i]=='*')
        {
            k=s.pop();
            l=s.pop();
            k=k*l;
            s.push(k);
        }
        else if(buf[i]=='+')
        {
            k=s.pop();
            l=s.pop();
            k=k+l;
            s.push(k);
        }
        else if(buf[i]=='-')
        {
            k=s.pop();
            l=s.pop();
            k=l-k;
            s.push(k);
        }
        else if(buf[i]=='/')
        {
            k=s.pop();
            l=s.pop();
            k=l/k;
            s.push(k);
        }
        else
        {
            c=(buf[i]-48);
            s.push(c);
        }
        i++;
    }
    k=s.pop();
    if(s.isempty())
    {
        cout<<k;
    }
    else 
    {

        cout<<"INVALID";
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Input:

> 11
>
> 1 2 + 3 * 6 + 2 3 + /    <-Working
>
> 11
>
> 3 5 * 2 / 11 3 / 7 * +    <-not Working because of 11 in input

Kindley help solving this problem or give an better logic to differentiate between numbers and operators.
Complete Code can be viewed [here](http://pastebin.com/nLYgZPvc).

Answer (score 0):

To read the input, and split it into what compiler theory calls "tokens", you need a simple lexical analyzer, or scanner, but slightly more advanced than the just-read-a-character version you have.

A technique used in the simple scanner given in (the previous edition of) the "dragon book" (Aho, Sethi, Ullman: Compilers - Principles, Techniques, and Tools, 1986) is to read a character, and if it is a digit put it back in the input (with ungetc in C), and then read an integer normally. If it is not a digit, handle it as an operator.

Comment: Please Read Documentation and make Effort .!

Answer (score 0):

Before applying any operand, you are just popping one digit. There should be a loop to pop all digits until another operator is found, and concatenate the digits to make a number. For example:

1+23+3

After first '+' operator, there should be a loop to pop both 2 and 3 ( generally until next operator is found). Then convert it to number 23 and apply the operator to 1 and 23.

Comment: This seems unnecessarily convoluted, contrary to how stack machines usually work, and also needlessly mixing the scanner phase with calculations. Why would you want to push single digits on the stack, instead of the complete integers?